# < a > Link only sending part of the URL in PHP email with mailgun

Tags: php, html, string, email, concatenation

This is fairly simple but my syntax seems to be off somehow...trying to send an html based email with mail-gun and the link in the email is only returning part of the href:

This half of the link up to regkey_email: http://www.hospitaldatasolutions.com/php/login.php?regkey_email=

heres my line:

```
$out_address = "<a href='http://www.hospitaldatasolutions.com/php/login.php?regkey_email='.$returnkey.'&email_val='.$email.'#logreg_signupbox'>Link</a>";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the wrong quotes in your concatenation. Your string is using double quotes as delimiters but your concatenation is using single quotes.

```
$out_address = "<a href='http://www.hospitaldatasolutions.com/php/login.php?regkey_email=".$returnkey."&email_val=".$email."#logreg_signupbox'>Link</a>";
```

Comment: It worked thank you, I don't know what I was thinking but I guess I thought it was the other way around and that concatenation was done with single quotes only. Even with that said my code didn't make sense still. Need more coffee xD